# http post with formdata and other field control not going to java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJs. I am trying to upload a image file (.bmp,.jpg, etc) along with its label through Jax-RS post rest API but my control in not going into java post api from my angularjs controller.

While debugging the control is not coming into java file. Could you please help to understand what si wrong in my code.

myfile.html

```
Label of File: <input type="text" name="iconlabel" data-ng-model="imporLabelName"><br>
Import a File: <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myfile" data-file-model="myfile"><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ng-click="uploadfile();">Submit
                </button>
```

myFileController

```
define([ '{angular}/angular' ], function(angular) {
var module = angular.module('myFile', [ 'ngResource', 'colorpicker-dr' ]);

module.controller('myFileController', [ '$scope', '$sce', '$http', '$location', '$window', 'w20MessageService'
,function($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $window, w20MessageService) {
    
            var config = { 
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": undefined,
                    }
                };
       
            /*** Modale for MyFile **/
            $scope.openMyFile = function() {
                $("#myfile").modal("show");
            };
            
            $scope.uploadfile = function() {
                $scope.file = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
                alert('LabelName = '+$scope.imporLabelName);
                
                var formData = new $window.FormData();
                formData.append("label", $scope.imporLabelName);
                formData.append("file", $scope.file);
                alert('File = '+$scope.file);
                var url = "uploadfile/label="+$scope.imporLabelName;
                alert("URL = "+url);
                $http.post(url,$scope.formData,config).success(function(response) {
                    $scope.result = "SUCCESS";
                }).error(function(response, status) {
                    if (status === 400) {
                        w20MessageService.addMessageErreur(data.message, "msgGererParam");
                    } else {
                        w20MessageService.addMessageErreur("eox.message.error.load.traitement", "msgGererParam");
                    }
                });
              $("#myfile").modal("hide");
            };
        } ]);
return {
    angularModules : [ 'digitalJes' ]
};
});
```

java api code

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadfile/{label}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response uploadFile(@PathParam("label") String label, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {

    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setNoCache(true);
    return Response.ok(uploadFileUtil.uploadFile(label, fileInputStream, fileInputDetails)).cacheControl(cc).build();
}
```

Error Code and Error Message

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
>
> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
 @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails
```

Seems both of the `fileInputStream` and `fileInputDetails` variables are initializing from `file` parameter. Also in `html` the field is

```
...
Import a File: <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myfile" data-file-model="myfile"><br>
```

Here **id="myFile"** and **name="myfile"** and you are receiving those as **"@FormDataParam("file")"**.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I made the changes as mentioned above but I am getting same error.

Comment: I'm not sure though but is it correct? `var url = "uploadfile/label="+$scope.imporLabelName;` shouldn't it be `uploadfile/"+$scope.imporLabelName` ?

Comment: @AnkitFulzele Just change the url. with `var url = "uploadfile/"+$scope.imporLabelName;` and check if error persist.

Comment: @Rahul i tried by changing the URL also but the error remains same.

Comment: Then it's hard to guess. Better if you also add the stack trace.. Lets see whats wrong with input parameters..

Comment: @Rahul-  your answer has helped me to do the research in right direction, so accepting your answer.

Comment: @afulz29 Happy to help! Thanks. :)